# How do i access django form's image field in js code

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am building a BlogApp and I am Build a feature of `preview image before save into Database`. BUT at the last moment, I am stuck on a Problem.

As i did before, I used to access image field in template like `{{ form.image }}` but i put js code in template for preview the selected image in `Choose file`.

create_blog_post.html

General method for choose image field `Choose file` in browser `{{ form.image }}.

```
    {{ form.image|as_crispy_field }}
```

js code in create_blog_post.html

```
<input type="file" id="uploadImage" name="termek_file" class="file_input" 
multiple/>
<div id="result" class="uploadPreview">

<script>

window.onload = function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    var filesInput = document.getElementById("uploadImage");
    filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      var files = event.target.files;
      var output = document.getElementById("result");
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        if (!file.type.match('image'))
          continue;
        var picReader = new FileReader();
        picReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
          var picFile = event.target;
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
            "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";
          output.insertBefore(div, null);
        });        
        picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }

    });
  }
}


</script>
```

**The Problem**

I have no idea , how to access `{{ form.image }}` attribute in js code, which can show both `Preview before save` and `upload that image`.

**What have i tried**

1). I have seen many answers on SO but nothing works.

2). Tried many methods BUT nothing works.

Any idea would be appreciated on , How to access `{{ form.image }}` in js code.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your code is about but I think you just need to access the value given by `{{ form.image }}`

So do the following

```
const theWantedThing = "{{ form.image }}"
```

If you didn't include the quotes javascript will through an error

Also, this uses Django HTML template, so make sure that your javascript code is included in the HTML page, if it was in a separate file then this won't work